# Understanding how an image file is printed through fprintf

Tags: c++, image, printf

I am actually working on a framework which implements a Path Tracer. I am having issues at understanding how the final image is written. The result is correct and the image looks nice (low number of samples):

[image]

but I have to understand how the code works since (according to me) something works is weird with the indices. This is the code in short:

```
struct Vec {
double x, y, z;                  // position, also color (r,g,b)
Vec(double x_ = 0, double y_ = 0, double z_ = 0){ x = x_; y = y_; z = z_; }
};

Vec *c = new Vec[width * height];

for (int y = 0; y<height; y++){// Loop over image rows
    for (unsigned short x = 0; x<width; x++) {  // Loop cols
        Vec r = calculatePixelColor(x,y);
        int i = (height - y - 1) * width + x;
        c[i] = c[i] + r;
    }
}

FILE *ff = fopen("image.ppm", "w");         // Write image to PPM file.
fprintf(ff, "P3\n%d %d\n%d\n", width, height, 255);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
    Vec pixel = c[x + y * width];
    int red = CLAMP((int)(sqrtf(pixel.x) * 255.0f), 0, 255);
    int green = CLAMP((int)(sqrtf(pixel.y) * 255.0f), 0, 255);
    int blue = CLAMP((int)(sqrtf(pixel.z) * 255.0f), 0, 255);
    fprintf(ff, "%d %d %d ", (red), (green), (blue));
}
fclose(ff);
```

Now, we have a pointer to Vec named `c` which contains all the informations of the pixels. This info are stored according to the index `i = (height - y - 1) * width + x;` . It means that the Vec* `c` starts describing the image from the last row. So, the first Vec pointed by `c` is the pixel at the bottom-left corner of the image (if I am not wrong). Therefore, if I am right, this leads me asking: how does `fprintf` work? According to the documentation it just writes down the stream from the top to the bottom.. so in theory the image should be flipped. Where is the trick?

Comment: Most probably the format you're writing th image into is defined bottom-to-tom. TGA, for example, is defined that way.

Comment: bottom-to-top images are not rare.  As a matter of fact, a Windows BMP can be defined this way, depending on the bitmap info header's `biHeight` attribute.

Comment: ok.. let's imagine that the .ppm image I am using is defined as you said bottom to top. If now I take another format which is defined top to bottom (jpeg? I don't know if it is defined like that) and I print it in the same way as shown above in the code, then the image would be flipped, am I right?

Comment: @Quentin but, am I right with the indices then? I mean, is it correct what I said about the way pixel's info are stored in the Vec _c_ ?